# How do i run different versions of grails on one windows machine and let them interact with each other?

Tags: grails

I am running an application on grails **2.3.7**. Now I try to develop a second application which runs on grails **3.3.9**. I would like them to run on the same windows machine at the same time.
In the end, I would like them to interact with each other.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to manage multiple versions of Grails on the same machine.

You could download as many versions as you like:

```
c:\tools\grails-2.5.4
c:\tools\grails-3.3.10
```

If you set `GRAILS_HOME` to `c:\tools\grails-2.5.4` and add `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin:` to the front of your `PATH`, you will be using Grails 2.5.4.  If you set `GRAILS_HOME` to `c:\tools\grails-3.3.10` and add `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin:` to the front of your `PATH`, you will be using Grails 3.3.10.

**EDIT**

Also note that you don't have to mess with any of that if you are using the `grailsw` that is in an existing project.  You don't need to set PATH or GRAILS_HOME or any of that for Grails (you will for the JDK).  For an existing Grails project with the wrapper in it, simply use the `grailsw` that is in the project instead of a Grails command that is on your `PATH`.  You can have different projects configured with different wrappers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! My main goal is to work with both versions of grails ( in this case also different versions of java ) at the same time. If i just want to manage the versions i would like to use sdkMan or something like that. But the point is to use the different versions at the same time.

Comment: The above technique will work for using as many different versions of Grails at the same time as you like.  You can't run 2 different versions of Grails in the exact same process, but that wouldn't even make sense.  If you have 2 different process with 2 different environment settings, they can use 2 different versions of Grails.  The same is true for more than 2 versions of Grails.

Comment: You can open a terminal, set `GRAILS_HOME` to point to whatever version of Grails you want to use, ensure that `%GRAILS_HOME%\bin` is at the front of your path, and you will be using that version of Grails in that terminal.  Leave that running and open another terminal and do the same thing but point `GRAILS_HOME` to a different version of Grails.  Now you have 2 terminals configured at the same time, with 2 different versions of Grails.